# Не работает SVG в браузере FF

Tags: html, css, svg, firefox

Всем привет!

Не работает SVG код в браузере Firefox

```css
.equilizer {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.bar {
  fill: DeepPink;
  width: 18px;
  animation: equalize 1.25s steps(25, end) 0s infinite;
}

.bar:nth-child(1) { 
  animation-duration: 1.9s;
}

.bar:nth-child(2) { 
  animation-duration: 2s;
}

.bar:nth-child(3) { 
  animation-duration: 2.3s;
}

.bar:nth-child(4) { 
  animation-duration: 2.4s;
}

.bar:nth-child(5) { 
  animation-duration: 2.1s;
}

@keyframes equalize {
  0% {
    height: 60px;
  }
  4% {
    height: 50px;
  }
  8% {
    height: 40px;
  }
  12% {
    height: 30px;
  }
  16% {
    height: 20px;
  }
  20% {
    height: 30px;
  }
  24% {
    height: 40px;
  }
  28% {
    height: 10px;
  }
  32% {
    height: 40px;
  }
  36% {
    height: 60px;
  }
  40% {
    height: 20px;
  }
  44% {
    height: 40px;
  }
  48% {
    height: 70px;
  }
  52% {
    height: 30px;
  }
  56% {
    height: 10px;
  }
  60% {
    height: 30px;
  }
  64% {
    height: 50px;
  }
  68% {
    height: 60px;
  }
  72% {
    height: 70px;
  }
  76% {
    height: 80px;
  }
  80% {
    height: 70px;
  }
  84% {
    height: 60px;
  }
  88% {
    height: 50px;
  }
  92% {
    height: 60px;
  }
  96% {
    height: 70px;
  }
  100% {
    height: 80px;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="equilizer" viewBox="0 0 128 128">
  <g>
    <title>Audio Equilizer</title>
    <rect class="bar" transform="translate(0,0)" y="15"></rect>
    <rect class="bar" transform="translate(25,0)" y="15"></rect>
    <rect class="bar" transform="translate(50,0)" y="15"></rect>
    <rect class="bar" transform="translate(75,0)" y="15"></rect>
    <rect class="bar" transform="translate(100,0)" y="15"></rect>
  </g>
</svg>
```

[ссылка на codepen](https://codepen.io/geoffgraham/pen/XmMJqj)

В других браузерах все работает отлично, в чем проблема? 
Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: https://codepen.io/geoffgraham/pen/XmMJqj

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в том, что в данном случае `width` и `height` элемента `rectangle` должны быть указаны как атрибуты элемента `rectangle`, а не свойства атрибута `style`. Firefox пытается найти именно атрибуты элемента `rectangle`, но не находит.
Имеется в виду, width и height следует задавать так:

```
<rect width="18" height="10">
```

Но тогда будут проблемы с анимацией, потому что анимация у Вас тоже прописана через css. Могу предложить вот такой [вариант решения](https://jsfiddle.net/HellLena/hs65to6y/7/), когда все свойства и анимация осуществляются через **svg**:

```
<rect width="18" height="10" x="75" y="15" fill="#ff1493">
      <animate attributeName="height" 
               dur="1.2s" 
               fill="freeze"
               values="10; 100; 30; 50; 40; 30; 10"               
               repeatCount="indefinite"
               />
 </rect>
```

Анимацию можно настроить в атрибутах:
`dur` - длительность анимации
`values` - это все значения, через которые будет проходить столбец (их можно сделать больше/меньше, как нравится)

Comment: Но с атрибутами css-анимация работать не будет.